# React-flowbite project content is not centered

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, flowbite

I'm having a hard time understanding why my whole page is not centred. I use Flowbite with React.
I put the whole project into a container since I want the content to be in the middle, not full-screen width.

Thanks in advance.

[image: iphone 12 mobile view]
[image: google chrome view]